# Does Starling City have active subway or not?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrow, arrowverse

In *Arrow* season 1 episode 18 *Salvation*, we learn that Starling City doesn't currently have a subway, it used to, but it's now abandoned. The tracks of the old subway were used by a villain in that episode and the subway logo was shown:

[image]

In season 3 episode 7 *Draw Back Your Bow*, Arrow has a fight at what looks to be an abandoned station of the same subway (with the same logo). When he and a villainess fall down on the tracks, a train appears almost immediately. But this time, there is no indication that she planned this and somehow made the train appear at the right time. To me, this seems to indicate that the subway is regularly used.

[image]

What could explain this? Did something change in the time between the two episodes and did (parts of) the subway network start to be used again? Or is there some other explanation why would a train ride on an abandoned track?

Comment: Maybe the subway isn't for consumer use? All commercial freight? Was it a a passenger train? Not a subway system but regular train that happens to go underground or use old subway rails? Like the train Barry takes to Starling.

Comment: Consider NYC. There are abandoned stations that are no longer part of the modern subway or above ground rail systems.

Answer (score -3):

Star City has an abandoned subway system, but not a functioning one. The subway has been used a couple of times as a good place to have fight scenes and other "evil and secretive" lairs. It is also used in The Flash by Gorilla Grodd as a living place. However that was more the sewers. The subway station is meant to be abandoned and discontinued. The city has more buses and on-ground railway. We have seen this a few times and especially when characters travel from Central City to Starling City. We have also heard them saying this.

Comment: Then how do you explain the train from the season 3 episode I mentioned?

Comment: @svick Sorry but I don't remember that episode. What I can vaguely remember is that the train was abandoned and then forcefully started to be used in the subway? Is that so, do we actually see the train being used and moving?